Cut-off based on an ordinal variable in unbalanced panel data
I am currently looking for an appropriate statistical analysis for my research questions. I have a continuous variable (score) and an ordinal variable (test). Score is quadratically related to Test, i.e. it first increases and then decreases. I want to define a cut-off for test, based on the level of test at which score peaks. Based on the cut-off for test, I would like to split my data set and run subsequent analyses. Of note, I have longitudinal, unbalanced panel data, so some subjects would be analyzed 2 - 7 times.
I figured that using an LMM (lme4) with test as the ordinal factor would be the way to go. Based on the model summary, I could just select the level with the largest beta. However, the procedure sounds a bit strange to me, do you have any ideas on how to improve it?

Why do you want to break up your continuous variable? This is usually not good practice.

@StephanKolassa I want to break up the ordinal variable test, which is a common practice with the kind of test

Yes, this is a common practice in many fields. And it is still bad practice. Have you looked at the page I linked in my comment? Also, if there is indeed a quadratic relationship as you describe and you want to break based on test, then you will get two cutoffs for score: high test will be associated with medium scores, whereas low test will be associated with both low and high scores. Is that what you want?

I agree with you and I appreciate your input. Perhaps I should go into more detail to explain.
My goal is not to predict test from score. Rather, I want to use  score in an early stage of the disease to predict later severity of symptoms. Ultimately, I want to say
"Individuals who have higher score scores in the early stages of their disease
are at greater risk for the progression of their symptom - Score is able to
identify vulnerable individuals."

A) Test measures the severity of symptoms. It decreases with symptom severity & its
cut-offs are used to select samples. Test can distinguish between early and late phases of symptoms, BUT it is insensitive to subtle changes in symptoms in early phases
(Therefore useless to identify vulnerable individuals).
B) Score can fill this gap because it is sensitive to early changes in symptoms.

C) However, Score takes on a quadratic shape over time, depending on the severity of the symptoms (maximum at moderate severity).
Therefore, I need to identify the point up to which score is "useful", i.e. I need to
to identify the early phase of the disease.
Using Test to identify this phase is of clinical use, since test is used in my field anyway. @StephanKolassa

@StephanKolassa
